# Windows 10 Update (Something went wrong. Try to reopen settings later)

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

Everytime i enter windows update i cant see nothing in Windows Update tab, only "Something went wrong. Try to reopen settings later" .
3 days have went by of me trying to fix this, but nothing is working...

The troubleshoot shows nothing wrong...
Tried to reset the pc but i got an error (something went wrong)...
When i try to scan the disk it always gives me an error
Did sfc /scandisk in safe mode there was no problem

Comment: As a first step here, try updating all computer drivers. Get the manufacturer's Driver Update App, update all drivers, do a final restart and test.  Then try a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link.

Comment: See this>>>>https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027322/windows-update-troubleshooter

Answer (score 1):

yes the problem is the UsoSvc, this service is essential for Windows updates to work, open regedit and navigate to :-

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\UsoSvc

In the right payne locate "start" and right click on it select modify in the value data box that opens change the 4 to 2, restart computer and try updates now. The default setting for this key is 2 which equates to automatic start 4 disables the service.

Comment: that solve issue or just enable "window orchiestrator update" because was disable by Wub 1_1 and new version is 1.5 fix this issue renable this services